# Restarting Page Numbers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to generate a few documents in the same Word file with VBA. For each document, the page number should start over at 1.

I've tried using code from stackoverflow as well as recording various macros and using that code, but when I run my macro, it doesn't work. The really strange thing is that I have this code in 2 places in my macro and it works in the 2nd place but not the first and I can't figure out why.

-Code to generate the first document

```
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If
If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
    ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
With Selection.HeaderFooter.PageNumbers
    .NumberStyle = wdPageNumberStyleArabic
    .HeadingLevelForChapter = 0
    .IncludeChapterNumber = False
    .ChapterPageSeparator = wdSeparatorHyphen
    .RestartNumberingAtSection = True
    .StartingNumber = 1
End With
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
```

-Code to generate the 2nd document

In the code that is supposed to reset the page number to #1 on page 5 of the document, the cursor instead moves up to the first page of the document and resets the page number to 1 there, which doesn't do anything because that is the first page of the document. I can't seem to get the cursor to stay where it's supposed to, on the first page of the 2nd document. The weirdest thing is that I have this same code later in the macro and it works there.

Comment: "For each document" - implies a loop of some kind. Having "this same code later in the macro" is a problem; there should be a way to parameterize that code and invoke it from the two places that need to run it.

Comment: I tried that before (tried it again just now.) I made a function and included the same code in the function and called it from the 2 different locations. I got the exact same result; it worked for the 2nd break but not the 1st break.

Answer (score 1):

You have inserted a section break but you don't have any code to set the .LinkToPrevious property to false.  Consequently your new section is likely just continuing on the previous section Heading.  This is why the cursor jumps to the first page.

To solve your problem you need to ensure the insertion point is in the new section and then you need to use .HeaderFooter.LinktoPrevious=false.

You may need to be quite specific with the .LinktoPrevious property and link it to the correct header or footer.  In case you hadn't realised there are three of each for each section.

Comment: Thank you! I added:
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
to the beginning of the sub that restarts the page numbers and now it works!